# Escaping ampersand in javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I try to replace the string "1/2" with an HTML character with this line:

```
$(this).text(($(this).text().replace('1/2','&frac12;')));
```

it is instead replaced with `&amp;frac12;`

How can I escape the ampersand (&) in javascript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to deal in HTML, then just deal in HTML:

```
$(this).html(($(this).html().replace('1/2','&frac12;')));
```

That said, the escaped JavaScript representation of the character is `"\u00BD"`, it should be simpler to just use `"½"` though.

Comment: It worked! Just for clarification. If I use text() later the string will interpreted as HTML?

Comment: If you use `text()` then you'll get text out and it will expect text in. If you use `html()` then you'll get HTML out and it will expect HTML in.

Comment: To avoid two calls to `html()`, you can pass a function to it: `$(this).html(function(i, html) { return html.replace('1/2','&frac12;');});`

Answer (score 1):

Jquery.text() is used to insert & properly escape text. So It is normal that & becomes &amp;.

To accomplish what you want to do use .html() instead of .text() in both occurences.